# std::invocable seems to be acting differently on functors within structs

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>

struct A {
  auto operator()(int const &) const noexcept {
    return 0;
  }
};
static_assert(std::invocable<A const &, int const &>);

struct X {
  struct B {
    auto operator()(int const &) const noexcept {
      return 0;
    }
  };
  static_assert(!std::invocable<B const &, int const &>); // Why?
};

static_assert(!std::invocable<X::B const &, int const &>); // Why?

void foo()
{
    int x = 1;
    A a;
    X::B b;
    std::invoke(a, x);
    std::invoke(b, x);
}
```

On godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/z/eT857zfrb

Results seem consistent between gcc, clang, and MSVC.  Why does `std::invocable` fail on the sub-`struct`?  The function `foo` seems to show that they are both "invocable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point where you write `static_assert(!std::invocable<B const &, int const &>);`, within `X`, `X` is not yet a complete type. As [cppreference states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)

> If an instantiation of a template [in the `std::is_invocable` family] depends, directly or indirectly, on an incomplete type, and that instantiation could yield a different result if that type were hypothetically completed, the behavior is undefined.

In this case, you are depending on the incomplete type `X`. (I'm sure the standard has a more detailed explanation.) `std::invocable` is defined in terms of a requires clause using `std::invoke` (at least, according to cppreference; GCC appears to use `std::is_invocable` directly), and `std::invoke` is defined to depend on `std::is_invocable` (though again, it appears this is not exactly the case in the implementations), so this `static_assert` is actually causing UB (hence the implementations aren't *wrong* for their odd behavior.)

If you *remove* the `static_assert` within `X`, then the UB is removed and an assertion outside `X` will start having the correct behavior.

```
struct X {
  struct B {
    auto operator()(int const &) const noexcept {
      return 0;
    }
  };
  // UB!: static_assert(!std::invocable<B const &, int const &>);
};
static_assert(std::invocable<X::B const &, int const &>); // passes
```

Comment: Well, that was subtle.  I ran into this problem when writing a class that created a `std::unordered_set` using a hash functor that was designed for heterogeneous lookup.  The functor was defined in the class, and the declaration of the set using it within the class failed due to the inability of the functor to pass the invocability test.  Thanks very much for your explanation.